# Sorta Complicated: Desktop Locations

Tags: desktop, storage

I have recently moved my desktop location (using properties menu) and changed it to E: (Hard drive 1TB) and then I installed a really big game (50 GB) and now i want to move the desktop into a folder in the E:.

So I want the desktop location to be E:\Desktop instead of E: (root). If I try to move the desktop location back to default (C:\users[me]\desktop), I get an error message that says:

```
 Failed to build the lost of regular subdirectories under "E:\System Volume Information". Access is denied.
```

And if it did work, my C:\ doesn't have enough space to move the 50 GB game onto the C:\ to then move back to E:\Desktop

And also if I try to move Desktop Location from E:\ to E:\Desktop, It says it cant move to a child but the location is on the root.

To Summarize: I want to move my Desktop Location from E:\ to E:\Desktop but there is a problem of storage if I restore location and move back to E:\ and if I try to move it to a child E:\Desktop, it says it can't move to a child.

Thanks if you can help,

Dammit Sniper Elite 4.

Comment: Can you temporarily add another drive, move it to that drive, and then move it back to E:\Desktop?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No, because my storage isn't enough

Did I state that in the post?If I didn't, I'm sorry and also I cant

Comment: @JeffZeitlin and also it has an error that says

Failed to build the lost of regular subdirectories under "E:\System Volume Information". Access is denied.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Can you install a new physical drive, say F: - I don't think attaching a large USB drive will work for this - then move the desktop to the new physical drive (F:\), then afterward, move it back to E:\Desktop?

Comment: You may also have to do this as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the System Volume Information folder and size limits are getting in the way of Windows moving this itself, it is probably best to do this manually.

First, we need to point Windows at the Desktop location you want to use.

1. Create the folder structure you want. (E:\Desktop)
2. Open `regedit.exe`.
3. Navigate to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders*
4. Double click the *Desktop* value.
5. Change the *Value data* field to `E:\Desktop`
6. Click OK.

Next, we manually move only the files and folders we want in the new Desktop location. The System Volume Information folder should be invisible, making that easy to skip. Generally, you should be able to *Select all* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click the items you want to exclude. Cut and paste the files and folders into E:\Desktop.

After this, you'll need to log out and back in or restart `explorer.exe`.

---

**Note:** It is generally a good idea to also update the *Desktop* value in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders* as well, but this is not necessary in most cases.

From [The long and sad story of the Shell Folders key](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973):

> [T]he "Shell Folders" key exists solely to permit four programs written in 1994 to continue running on the RTM version of Windows 95.

Comment: I have done all the steps but on my desktop (actual screen) it doesn't update to everything back? (I did all the steps, folders gone & moved to my E:\Desktop but it doesn't show up on my actual monitor desktop?

Comment: @ThePiggie Sorry about that, it's the `User Shell Folders` key, not the `Shell Folders` key. I've updated my answer with more information.